# Not ideal pi-filter

Tags: capacitor, resistors, circuit-analysis, filter, inductor

What is the best 'real-world' represenation of a not ideal Pi-filter? Or how can change it that I can model it the best way?

[image]

Comment: I don't know what you mean by not-ideal?

Comment: @Andyaka In the real world a capacitor and inductor have loses?!

Comment: Yes, but those losses will shape the filter and prevent very odd spectral responses. They are fundamental to the filter.

Answer (score 2):

A capacitor can be modelled with a series resistor and a series inductor. Additionally, it can have a parallel resistor to represent dielectric losses. Going further, a capacitor can have its value modulated by the applied voltage and, the dielectric losses can be frequency dependent.

An inductor will have series resistance that represents the dc winding resistance but it can have a series resistance that also represents the losses due to skin effect and winding proximity effect. There is also another resistor that represents core losses. The inductor can be very complex to model. It also has a self resonant frequency that is modelled with a parallel capacitor.

How far do you want to take this is down to common sense and knowledge of the target application.

Having said all that, resistive loss elements can and are used to shape the frequency response of any order or type of filter so, there is no real meaning to the term "non-ideal" in many filters because those lossy components temper the spectral shape into what is needed by the application.